# How to go about GARP?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I wanted to download the tool `GARP`(genetic algorithm for rule set production).I came across this site:http://landshape.org/enm/garp-modelling-system-users-guide-and-technical-reference/
which tells to download the tool from this site:http://biodi.sdsc.edu.But it is not
opening.Can anyone tell where I can download it from and also a tutorial as I want to run
the tool on data set mentioned in this paper:`species distribution modelling by David R.B stockwell`.Also where could I find the data set mentioned in this paper??

Comment: Did you write the authors of that paper already? There's Stockwell's e-mail address in the first link you've stated.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah its the same site its not working !!!

Comment: There seems to be an implementation in the [openModeller](http://openmodeller.sourceforge.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=8&Itemid=4). Such questions are hard to answer, I think you should use Google and spend a day to hunt for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although that site is dead, you can still download the files from the internet archive:
[www.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20051127012211/http://biodi.sdsc.edu/Doc/GARP/).

I've checked that garp.zip is good.

You might want to consider the windows port [DesktopGARP](http://www.nhm.ku.edu/desktopgarp/FAQ.html), which appears to be a reimplementation of the algorithm.